# How to have multiple php projects in same port in docker on vps server?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I have two php web applications,

1. http://example1.com
2. http://example2.com

I am using docker containers to host the project on vps server. The docker container have the following images,

1. Nginx
2. mysql
3. php-fpm

For the first project (http://example1.com), the port number is bind like below,

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

Now, I am able to access my site on browser using http://example1.com.

But here for my second project, I have bind the **port to 81** because docker cannot bind on the same port,

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "81:80"
```

I can able to access my site in browser by http://example2.com:81, but in production we will not use port numbers on browsers.

How to overcome this?

Comment: If those are 2 different domains(vhosts), you can define 2 different `server_name`s with one listening port.

Comment: How would you solve this problem without Docker?  I can think of two approaches – a single reverse proxy server with name-based virtual services, or multiple IP addresses on the host – and both of these would have Docker equivalents, but Docker doesn't solve this problem on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You need a route the traffic at the HTTP level to be able to route these domain names:

1. http://example1.com
2. http://example2.com

You can do a number of things, but here are a few options:

1. [traefik](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/) can act a router
2. Setup another nginx container in your compose on port 80 as a reverse proxy. See this [article](https://www.bogotobogo.com/DevOps/Docker/Docker-Compose-Nginx-Reverse-Proxy-Multiple-Containers.php) for inspiration.

   Your setup would something look like this

```
services:
  nginx-reverse-proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
    - /host/path/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
    - 80:80
    restart: always
    networks:
    - example

  example1:
    image: nginx
    container_name: example1
    networks:
    - example

  example2:
    image: nginx
    container_name: example2
    networks:
    - example

networks:
  example:
```